# How to outline element on hover inside iframe without affecting layout?

Tags: javascript, css

I wish to highlight elements of a page on hover. The page is inside an iframe.

I am using a css class to give blue outline:

```
.highlight {
   outline: 2px solid #08C !important;
}
```

**Attempt #1: adding class to element hovered**

First I tried adding the css class to the element hovered. To ensure the outline was fully visible I had to alter the css position of surrounding elements to 'relative' and play with z-index values. But this broke the layout in some cases (image going to next line for example).

***Problem: either outline is not fully visible, or I break the layout***

**Attempt #2: adding new DOM element on top of hovered element**

In order to avoid affecting the design of the page I thought it would be better to create a new div with blue border and position it on top of the existing element.

This works ok in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aDGbX/1/

but not inside an iframe so far. (I do not see the outline anywhere).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('body').find(".hoverClass").bind("hover", function() {   
     thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    var pos = $('#'+thisId).offset();
     var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).height();

    jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: 'highlighterDiv',
    }).appendTo('body');

    $("#highlighterDiv").css( {position: 'absolute', top: pos.top, left: pos.left, 'z-index': '99' } );
    $("#highlighterDiv").css( {width: w, height: h} );
    $("#highlighterDiv").addClass('highlight');
    $("#highlighterDiv").show();

 });

});
​
```

***Problem: not working inside iframe so far***

**Question:**

Is the second attempt a better method? Or what would you recommend?

Comment: I'm sure that you can't select elements within an iFrame, unless you have control over the source. Do you have control?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks I am pretty sure you can select elements within iFrame because I have seen it done (VisualWebsiteOptimizer.com ; you would have to sign in to see how they do it). I also made it work although with problems as I mentioned above. Not sure what you mean by having control over the source.